# Clojure metadata lost on certain forms

Tags: clojure, metadata

I am puzzled by the difference in behavior for the following expressions:

```
(pr (meta ^{:a 0} (list 1 2))) ;; prints nil returns nil

(pr (meta ^{:a 0} '(1 2)));; prints {:line 110, :column 20} returns nil

(pr (meta ^{:a 0} (range 1 3))) ;; prints nil returns nil

(pr (meta ^{:a 0} [1 2])) ;; prints {:a 0} returns nil
```

This is using clojure 1.8.0. I would welcome an explanation as to why the results differ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reader metadata is attached to the form that the reader returns. `meta` is, in each case, called with whatever that form evaluates to at runtime. There is no necessary link between one and the other.

If you need to attach metadata to a value at runtime, you can use `with-meta` to do that.

Let's have a look at what happens in each of the cases listed in the question:

1. `(pr (meta ^{:a 0} (list 1 2)))`

   Reader metadata is attached to the list structure `(list 1 2)`, but `meta` is applied not to this list structure, but to the value it evaluates to at runtime, which will be a freshly allocated list of two items with no metadata attached.
2. `(pr (meta ^{:a 0} '(1 2)))`

   Reader metadata is attached to the list structure `(quote (1 2))` (the single quote character is reader shorthand for `(quote …)`), but `meta` is applied not to this list structure, but to the value it evaluates to at runtime, which is the `(1 2)` list structure that the reader created when reading in this expression. This carries `{:line … :column …}` metadata, because the Clojure reader attaches that to certain types of forms for use in error messages and such.
3. `(pr (meta ^{:a 0} (range 1 3)))`

   Same as the first case above.
4. `(pr (meta ^{:a 0} [1 2]))`

   This is very similar to the `'(1 2)` case with the crucial difference that while non-empty lists need to be quoted if they are not to be treated as function/macro calls, vectors do not, and so the reader metadata is actually attached to the literal of interest – the vector – itself.

   This is doable with a list as well:

   ```
   (pr (meta ' ^{:a 0} (1 2)))
             ^ note the quote comes before the metadata
   ;; prints {:line 1, :column 14, :a 0}
   ```

   NB. the explicit reader metadata map got merged into the `{:line … :column …}` map that the reader adds by itself.